# Adding Private Repository in crucible

Tags: atlassian-crucible

I'm not able to add private repository in crucible. How can I add it?

I'm currently experiencing difficulties adding a private repository in Crucible. Could anyone please guide me on how to do it? Specifically, I would like to know the steps involved in adding a private repository and any requirements or permissions necessary for a successful integration.